# Stripe webhook will be disabled after a while

Tags: stripe-payments

I've set a stripe webhook in my server by the following command via ssh:

`nohup ./stripe listen --forward-to https://example.com/stripe/webhook &`

The related service will be run perfectly and in the Stripe dashboard the registered webhook will be shown in `Listening` status but after a few days(like a week) the status of the webhook turns to `Disabled` in the Stripe dashboard, whereas when I check the Stripe service on the server, it's running.

[image]

Comment: Stripe CLI generates restricted keys that’re [valid for 90 days](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli/keys). Maybe this is your case?

Comment: @seeker I know this, but as a said it will be happened after around a week!

Comment: Nope :) You said you've ran `listen` command at that time. This does not mean that the keys were generated at the same time. Have you already checked their status in the [dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys)?

Comment: Do you receive an email saying "webhook delivery issues" from Stripe? Stripe will automatically disable a webhook if they can't send request to your endpoint: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#disable-logic

Comment: @orakaro, No I have not received the email.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe automatically disables webhooks that are not used for a few days by checking if the webhook is receiving 2xx HTTP status for a few days in a row or not.

ref: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#disable-logic